# Allow only numbers from 0 to 1

Tags: c++, while-loop, cin

I have this below but if i enter a letter I get an infinite loop.

What is the proper way to make it so that it only accepts the numbers 0 to 1, and no letters or other characters. It should accept numbers between like 0.1 ect 0.5

```
int alphaval = -1;
cout << "Enter a number between 0 and 1: ";
cin >> alphaval;
while (alphaval < 0 || alphaval > 1)
{
    cout << "Invalid entry! Please enter a valid value: ";
    cin >> alphaval;
}
```

Comment: How is alphaval declared?

Comment: Its declared before this sorry forgot to put it.

Comment: If you are trying to read a **double**, you generally do not want to declare an `int` type to hold it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note that `std::cin` will be in bad state if you enter values of unexpected type (such as string when int is expected). If a stream is in invalid state, then it will fail to read even valid input, and the loop will run infinitely. That seems to be your case, so you need to clear the stream **and** since the stream didn't the invalid input, you need to skip it (using `ignore` function):

```
double alphaval; //it must be double or float (as per your requirement)

cin >> alphaval;    
while (alphaval < 0 || alphaval > 1)
{
    cout << "Invalid entry! Please enter a valid value: ";

    //FIX
    cin.clear();  //clear bad flags!
    cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n'); //skip bad input

    cin >> alphaval; //read fresh!
}
```

Include `<limits>` header file for `std::numeric_limits<>`.

Comment: @crclayton: `int` will not read `.57` for example! The stream will fail and will be in invalid state.

Comment: @Nawaz should not it read the `.57` as `0` if declared as int?

Comment: @Tahlil: No.... it will fail when it sees `.` Note that such conversion (float to int, as you seem to think) is NOT done when reading values from stream.

Comment: If i type in any word when it asks for again in the  invalid entry text i get a loop that goes forever @Nawaz

Comment: @user3398034: You're doing things incorrectly. Please post the WHOLE code at `www.ideone.com`  (or pastebin) and give me the link.

Comment: @user3398034: Ohh.. I see. You need to skip the invalid input as well. See the edited answer.

Comment: Okay that works, but now if i Enter 0 or 1 it doesnt take it. It just asks me to enter it again? I want it to input 0 to 1 including 0 and 1

Comment: @user3398034: YOUR condition is WRONG. don't use `<=` use `<`.. and likewise, don't use `>=` use `>`. See this: http://ideone.com/AR32pN

Comment: Why am i getting invalid entry when entering 0?

Comment: And i have to input 0  twice for it to work or 1 twice?

Comment: The issue I am having now is that i have to enter 1 twice or 0 twice for it to work.

Comment: @user3398034: You want me to "imagine" what your current code is, or you want me to "see" it in order to help you?

Comment: my apologies i was seeing something wrong it worked.

Comment: My apologies @Nawaz I was using the wrong operators.

Answer (score 1):

define alphaval as float or double

```
double alphaval = 0.0;
//  YOUR CODE
cout << "Enter a number between 0 and 1";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
double alphaval = -1;
cout << "Enter a number between 0 and 1: ";
cin >> alphaval;
while (true)
{
    if(alphaval >= 0 && alphaval <= 1)
    {
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Invalid entry! Please enter a valid value: ";
        cin >> alphaval;
    } 
}
```